# Concatenate a Function Name in Lua

Tags: function, lua, concatenation

This is probably really simple but I'm new so here we go..

How would I code this:

```
local color1 = { 255,0,0 }
local color2 = { 1,200,1 }
local color3 = { 2,2,150 }
for i = 1, 3 do 
    local x = "color" .. i[i]
    print( x )
end
```

What I am looking for as output

```
255  
200  
150
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to put the color info in an array

```
local colors = {
    { 255,0,0 },
    { 1,200,1 },
    { 2,2,150 },
}

-- Iterating by hand:
for i=1, #colors do
    local rgb = colors[i]
    print(rgb[i])
end

-- ipairs is another way to do the same thing
for i, rgb in ipairs(colors) do
    print(rgb[i])
end
```

Comment: You should not use ipairs in 5.1+, it is a lot slower than `for i=1, #array do` and does the same thing.

Comment: @dualed: That sounds a bit like premature optimization and its a big matter of taste anyways from what I have heard. I really hate having to type the array name twice or having to create an extra variable if the array is the result of some expression.

Comment: It is a matter of 1 C function call per iteration vs. one increment operation, because the `#` operation is only called once and performs better than the `ipairs()` function anyway. And no it is not premature, it does the very same thing, costs you basically nothing to change, and you pointed it out specifically, so I only commented that it is not a good thing to use in Lua 5.1 and above. Probably not even before that, but the `#` operator was introduced in 5.1 so you would have to work around that. And *that* would be premature optimization.

Comment: @dualed: And why should I care if there is an extra function call per loop? Most stuff is not CPU bound anyway and its still going to tons of times faster than something like Python anyways.

Comment: Then don't. Since you seem to know exactly how often the OP executes that code, and how time-critical it is, I have nothing more to say.

Comment: @dualed: if that's true, why does 5.1 not deprecate ipairs?

Comment: @Eric Well.. I don't know, I don't contribute to the Lua project. There is however an `__ipairs` (and `__pairs`) meta method in 5.2 so it doesn't look like they want to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `color1`, `color2` and `color3` tables are static; you can try this approach:

```
local color1, color2, color3 = { 255,0,0 }, { 1,200,1 }, { 2,2,150 }
color = { color1 = color1, color2 = color2, color3 = color3 }
for i = 1, 3 do 
    local x = color["color"..i][i]
    print( x )
end
```

Output: http://codepad.org/qL5K3jNq